# Google+ link isn't valid

Tags: php, html, google-plus

I'm trying to paste my website's page link in my Google+ page comments, but its says "The link isn't valid".

I recently added Twitter Cards code to my pages HTML/PHP code, might it have affected it? How can I fix it, so that Google+ shows not just link, but card of the link, like in facebook when you paste link to comments section?

In my header include file, I added this to `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="<?php print $twitter_card ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="<?php print $twitter_username ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php print $twitter_title ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php print $twitter_description ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php print $twitter_img_url ?>" />
```

And in my beginning of PHP file:

```
<?php
$twitter_card = "summary_large_image";
$twitter_username = "@KnowledgiX";
$twitter_title = "A-vitamin (aka retinol) | KnowledgiX";
$twitter_description = "Everything you need to know about A-vitamin | Health";
$twitter_img_url = "http://www.knowledgix.com/images/title_img/02.carrots_(A).jpg";
?>
```

Comment: You need to provide the code/HTML that you have written for review. Without that I don't know how you expect to get an answer.

Comment: did you check if the html is being generated properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google+ doesn't support parenthesis ( ) in files name.

**Option 1:**

My file's name was "A-vitamin_(aka_retinol).php", so Google+ said its invalid link. But when I changed the file's name to "A-vitamin_aka_retinol.php", Google+ accepted the url and showed cards.
So it didn't have anything to do with my HTML/PHP code.

**Option 2 (*as @MrLister mentioned in comments*):**

If you want to keep parenthesis in your file's name, you can change parenthesis to %28 %29 in your url when adding it in Google+ comments.

Comment: Just curious. If you would have kept the parenthesis, and told Google the url was "A-vitamin_%28aka_retinol%29.php, would it have worked?

Comment: Hmm...good point @MrLister. I don't know, maybe it would have worked. I'll give it a try and inform you how it worked out.

Comment: @MrLister if I keep parenthesis and instead of ( ) I put this %28 %29 in url, it worked fine in Google+. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @RedRose you may include mr lister comment in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Google expects the url should be a publicly accessible URL and not a restricted one. E.g this will not work -  `localhost:anything` since it is something which is running on your local environment and hopefully  the reason I could deduce was that since google crawlers cannot run on the web page, they will not allow the link to be shared.
Same things were happening to URLs which were accessible only via VPN. Google cannot crawl these too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this for a site which is misconfigured to return a 404 status code, but still serves the full content.